# Formula for X & Y Co-ordinates to Latitude and Longitude?

Tags: excel, geolocation, formula

I have to convert X and Y coordinates into Latitude and Longitude using Excel Formula without Z coordinate.

```
X=6371*COS(C2)*COS(D2)
Y=6371*COS(C2)*SIN(D2)
C2( Lat), D2(long)
```

I have tried inverse of the above formula but unable to do that.

Comment: Could you give us some sample figures to work on plz and a link to where these two formulas come from? At the moment I don't understand how x and y coordinates on a spherical surface make sense, unless you are working over a very small area covered by a map and can approximate it to a flat surface.

Comment: Agreed, we need some kind of example and expected result. Do you want to convert decimal degrees (DD) into DMS?

Comment: To answer my own question, the formulas are explained well here https://www.intmath.com/vectors/3d-earth-geometry.php so x and y (and z) are just straight-line distances measured with cartesian coordinates using a plane through the equator. I think the question does make sense now - if you can project down onto this plane knowing the latitude and longitude of a place you can get its x and y values, so you can presumably do the opposite (though there might be 2 matches, one in the northern hemisphere and one in the southern hemisphere).

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of maths (to follow) you can get the following:

Longitude

```
=ATAN(F2/E2)
```

where E2 and F2 are X and Y

Latitude

```
=ACOS(SQRT(E2^2+F2^2)/6371)
```

So below I have started with the latitude and longitude of a famous northern city, converted them to X and Y coordinates, then converted them back into latitude and longitude. Because of the square root, there is actually a mirror image in the southern hemisphere.

[image]

The original equations can be written as:

```
X=R cos(lat) cos(long) ...(1)

Y=R cos(lat) sin(long) ...(2)
```

where R is the radius of the Earth in miles.

Dividing (2) by (1) gives

```
Y/X = tan (long)
```

or

```
long = atan(Y/X) ....(3)
```

Substituting (3) into (1) gives

```
X = R cos(lat) cos(arctan(Y/X))
```

but

```
cos(arctan(Y/X)) => X/sqrt(X^2 + Y^2)
```

(by considering a right-angled triangle with shorter sides X and Y)

so

```
X=R cos(lat) X / sqrt(X^2+Y^2)

cos(lat) = sqrt(X^2+Y^2) / X

lat = acos(sqrt(x^2+Y^2)/X) ....(4)
```

Equations (3) and (4) are used to determine the latitude and longitude from X and Y.